GCP VM networking issue - communication between vms
i am more Java developer than a system/cloud architect, yet i am stucked in position from which i see no way out.
On Google Cloud i have custom network named t with subnet t-eu which has a primary ipv4 range 192.168.0.0/24 this should yield
range for 254 network devices attached to the network. Some of the VM's on this network are using Google Cloud Optimized OS where we deploy our Docker containers via Cloud SDK (in pipelines).
One of suche VM is a Spring Boot Cloud Gateway (java) A which we are using route traffic across VM's (services). Until today our setup was working without any issues.
However suddenly this Compute Engine VM (we rely heavily on Instance Templates, and Instance groups) basically stoped working. Looking at the firewall rules (ingress/egress)
at port 8080/80 with logging enabled do not fail.
Spring Cloug Gateway with Eureka (Service discovery) B seems to rely on dns domain names. Using trace logs i can clearly see that traffic is routed to C - desired service.
From A i clearly see following:
Pattern "/file-storage-swagger" matches against value "/file-storage-swagger"
Route matched: FILE-STORAGE-SERVICE
RouteToRequestUrlFilter start
LoadBalancerClientFilter url chosen: http://my-service-managed-n03f.europe-west1-b.c.project-name.internal:8080/v3/api-docs
Connecting to [my-service-managed-n03f.europe-west1-b.c.project-name.internal/192.168.1.20:8080]

then suddenly connection dies. In front of our instance groups is Load Balancer which terminates the traffic after 30 second, which i believe its a default value. So each time we hit our gateway A
it asks B about location of C which under its domain name is located within t-eu-  subnet with ip address of 192.168.1.20. However it always times out.
I tried to use Connectivity Tests where i routed traffic from A to C using correct ports and ips and it always succeeds. There is nothing in logs,
nothing in Network Intelligence tools and so on. I tried to use tcpdump and other networking tools to capture slightles detail, but Cloud Optimized OS is really limited here.
I can ping directly the C vm, but telnet, trace does not work.
summary:

vm A cannot reach vm B
vm B has no issue with reaching vm A
A can ping B and B can ping A
A cannot traceroute, telnet, curl, whatever B
firewall rules seem to be working (Connectivity Test, Logs)

Edit: the problem was in automatic template creation
I used to create templates in instance templates via bitbucket pipeline
this is the command
gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container <name>-$ENV-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER \
    --project=<project-name>\
    --machine-type=$MACHINE_TYPE \
    --network-interface=subnet=<subnet>,no-address \
    --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE \
    --service-account=<service-acc> \
    --scopes=<scopes> \
    --region=<region> \
    --container-image=<docker-image> \
    --container-restart-policy=always \
    --container-privileged \
    --container-env=<envs> \
    --boot-disk-size=25 \
    --boot-disk-type=pd-balanced \
    --no-shielded-secure-boot \
    --shielded-vtpm \
    --shielded-integrity-monitoring \
    --labels=container-vm=<container-vm-name>

This stopped working, still dont know why, but when i created the template manually, everything was working, so now as a workaround i use latest tag on my docker images and delete active instances in managed group via script in my bitbucket pipeline
I will further investigate, why it stopped working, bcs approach i have now is not suitable, i need to create separate template manually if some configuration needs to be changed
The manual creation is pretty forward, i specify necessary config for the machine, attach docker image, set up individual access to sql and storage and put the template in my network and subnetwork

Can you confirm if the VM A, B and C are on the same VPC network? Because if it is on the same VPC network, firewall should not be an issue.
When you mentioned that you tried to use tcp dumps would that be the pre-installed toolbox? I suggest installing tcpdumps in the toolbox then try to packet capture vm a to vm b simultaneously.

I forgot to mention, I create instance templates in my pipeline on bitbucket and I update managed groups with these templates
I think the problem lies in creation of the template itself, when i create the template manually, it works fine, older templates work fine as well, when i copy the code from template creation, it does not run in cli anymore, bcs it does not recognise some minor arguments, still, when it's going through my pipeline(custom on bitbucket which worked fine until now), I get the timeout on HC and this weird connectivity problem, specified gcp sdk version too, but nothing

Does this mean that creating template manually resolved this concern? When you say manually can you share what manually did you do to help other users that have similar concern or will have the same concern in the future,

posted edit explanation above

Actually, after some time, google fixed their mistake and my old pipelines are working again :)

Allow me to share your comment as a solution to assist other users encountering a similar issue. The problem revolves around communication issues between VM instances, likely stemming from the automatic creation of a template.
To resolve this, manually creating a template and utilizing the latest tag on the Docker image seems to be a viable workaround. Additionally, deleting active instances in the managed group via a script in Bitbucket Pipeline can help address the issue.

I want to come to this later as this is temporary solution and does not meet standards
